# Facebook graph api not returning tasks after New Page Experience switch

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I used to call this api:

https://graph.facebook.com//accounts?access_token=&fields=name,access_token, tasks

And get back this response:

{
"data": [
{
"name": "",
"access_token": "",
"id": "",
"tasks": [
"ANALYZE",
"ADVERTISE",
"MESSAGING",
"MODERATE",
"CREATE_CONTENT",
"MANAGE"
]
}
]
}

After my page was migrated to New Page Experience by Facebook, then I just receive:

{
"data": [
{
"name": "",
"access_token": "",
"id": ""
}
]
}

Why is that? How can I get back the tasks as well? Is there a different way to receive tasks?
I still receive tasks for all pages that have not been migrated to new experience yet, so I suppose there is a connection with the migration.

Comment: Just wondering if you found the issue. I'm facing a similar problem with graph API after migrating to the new page experience